# Caesar Cipher Help, Figuring out spaces, integers, and special chars

Tags: c, string, char, caesar-cipher

I’m trying to make a Caesar Cipher in C, but I’m having trouble encrypting and decrypting spaces, integers, and special characters like `!`, `$`, `#`, etc. I have a simple code for figuring out the string parts and converting them. Any advice would be lovely! And advice to make my code better would help, too.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Ascii codes: 'a'=97, 'b' = 98, and so on.

void encrypt()
{
    char message[500], c;
    int i;
    int key;

    printf("Enter a message to encrypt: ");
    scanf("%s", &message);
    printf("Enter key: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        c = message[i];
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            c = c + key;
            if (c > 'z') {
                c = c - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
            }
            message[i] = c;
        } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            c = c + key;
            if (c > 'Z') {
                c = c - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
            }
            message[i] = c;
        }
    }

    printf("Encrypted message: %s", message);
}

void decrypt()
{
    char message[500], c;
    int i;
    int key;

    printf("Enter a message to decrypt: ");
    scanf("%s", &message);
    printf("Enter key: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        c = message[i];
        if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            c = c - key;
            if (c < 'a') {
                c = c + 'z' - 'a' + 1;
            }
            message[i] = c;
        } else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            c = c - key;
            if(c < 'A') {
                c = c + 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
            }
            message[i] = c;
        }
    }

    printf("Decrypted message: %s", message);
}

int main()
{
    encrypt();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the non-alpha characters?

Comment: Don't forget [`isalpha()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) exists.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be maintaining a constant array of special characters and use its index for encryption/decryption purpose.

Consider the following code snippet:

```c
const char specialCharacterList[] = "!@#$%&(){}[] +-*/'?.,;\"";


int getSpecialCharacterIndex(char c)
{
    int specialCharacterCount = strlen(specialCharacterList);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<specialCharacterCount; i++)
    {
        if(c == specialCharacterList[i])
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}


void encrypt(char givenMessage[], int shiftValue)
{
    char givenCharacter, encryptedCharacter;
    int messageLength = strlen(givenMessage);
    int i, specialCharacterIndex;
    for(i=0; i<messageLength; i++)
    {
        givenCharacter = givenMessage[i];
        if(isalpha(givenCharacter))
        {
            if(isupper(givenCharacter))
            {
                // handle upper case characters
            }
            else
            {
                // handle lower case characters
            }
        }
        else if(isdigit(givenCharacter))
        {
            //handle digits
        }
        else
        {
            specialCharacterIndex = getSpecialCharacterIndex(givenCharacter);
            if(specialCharacterIndex == -1)
            {
                printf("Unidentified character found: %c\n", givenCharacter);
                encryptedCharacter = ' ';
            }
            else
            {
                encryptedCharacter = specialCharacterList[(specialCharacterIndex+shiftValue) % strlen(specialCharacterList)];
            }
        }
        givenMessage[i] = encryptedCharacter;
    }
}
```

Here I've stored the special characters in `specialCharacterList[]` array. Using the `getSpecialCharacterIndex()` function, I retrieve the index of the special character in the array and perform operation on the index of the array.

Note: you can also include spaces, tabs, newlines etc in `specialCharacterList[]`.

If the character has not been included in the array, it will display on the console. And from that we can include it in `specialCharacterList[]` later.

On a different note, you mentioned that you want to handle spaces as well. In that case I would suggest you to use `gets()` instead of `scanf()` to get the input because `scanf()` will stop receiving inputs as soon as it encounters space.

**Drawback:**
This solution will be feasible only when both encryptor and decryptor have the same array for special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if character is in following range
**32–47 / 58–64 / 91–96 / 123–126** then it is special character.

Or This is the way I used

```
if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){
    c = c - key;

    if(c < 'a'){
        c = c + 'z' - 'a' + 1;
    }

    message[i] = c;
}
else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
    c = c - key;

    if(c < 'A'){
        c = c + 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
    }

    message[i] = c;
}
else{
    message[i] = c;
}
```

This would be pretty  simple

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is described at [Caesar cipher - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). You have figured out that the shift of the value will require you to consider the offset from the end of range, which is good. Where you run into problems, in both case is with your addition and subtraction of the `key` (shift) to the character and your subsequent test for greater than `'z'` or less than `'a'`:

```
        c = c + key;
        if (c > 'z') {
```

and

```
        c = c - key;
        if (c < 'a') {
```

If adding or subtracting `key` (shift value) does not result in a value greater than `'z'` or less than `'a'`, (and there is no guarantee they will or won't based on the `key` size), you are not applying any encoding or decoding at all unless your condition tests **true**.

With the algorithm there is a requirement that the `(x + n)` or `(x - n)` result must be between `0 - 25`. (see algorithm at link) That is what `% 26` is used to protect against when the value exceeds `25`, but you also must ensure the value is non-negative. You can satisfy this requirement by adding `26` and with a little algebra to arrive at an expression (one for uppercase and one for lowercase) that covers all cases. For example:

```
#define SIZE 26
...
int encipher (int c, int shift)
{
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
        /*
         *   c = 'A' + (c - 'A' + 'Z' - shift + 1 - 'A') % SIZE;
         *   c = 'A' + (c - 'A' - shift + 'Z' - 'A' + 1) % SIZE;
         *   where ('Z' - 'A' + 1 == SIZE)
         */
        c = 'A' + (c - 'A' - shift + SIZE) % SIZE;
    else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
        c = 'a' + (c - 'a' - shift + SIZE) % SIZE;
    
    return c;
}
```

and for decoding:

```
int decipher (int c, int shift)
{
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
        /*
         *   c = 'A' + (c - 'A' - ('Z' - shift + 1 - 'A')) % SIZE;
         *   c = 'A' + (c - 'A' - 'Z' + shift - 1 + 'A') % SIZE;
         *   c = 'A' + (c - 'Z' + shift - 1) % SIZE;
         *   where (c - 'Z' < 0) for (shift - 1 < SIZE)
         */
        c = 'A' + (c - 'Z' + shift - 1 + SIZE) % SIZE;
    else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
        c = 'a' + (c - 'z' + shift - 1 + SIZE) % SIZE;
    
    return c;
}
```

Adding a short example that allows you to enter the shift (your `key`) and the text to be encoded and decoded (up to 1024 characters, 1023 + the null character), you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 26
#define MAXC 1024

int encipher (int c, int shift)
{
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
        /*
         *   c = 'A' + (c - 'A' + 'Z' - shift + 1 - 'A') % SIZE;
         *   c = 'A' + (c - 'A' - shift + 'Z' - 'A' + 1) % SIZE;
         *   where ('Z' - 'A' + 1 == SIZE)
         */
        c = 'A' + (c - 'A' - shift + SIZE) % SIZE;
    else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
        c = 'a' + (c - 'a' - shift + SIZE) % SIZE;
    
    return c;
}

int decipher (int c, int shift)
{
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
        /*
         *   c = 'A' + (c - 'A' - ('Z' - shift + 1 - 'A')) % SIZE;
         *   c = 'A' + (c - 'A' - 'Z' + shift - 1 + 'A') % SIZE;
         *   c = 'A' + (c - 'Z' + shift - 1) % SIZE;
         *   where (c - 'Z' < 0) for (shift - 1 < SIZE)
         */
        c = 'A' + (c - 'Z' + shift - 1 + SIZE) % SIZE;
    else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
        c = 'a' + (c - 'z' + shift - 1 + SIZE) % SIZE;
    
    return c;
}

int main (void) {
    
    int n = 0, shift;
    char text[MAXC],
        encode[sizeof text],
        decode[sizeof text];
    
    fputs ("enter shift: ", stdout);    /* just use text for both inputs */
    if (!fgets (text, MAXC, stdin))
        return 1;
    
    if (sscanf (text, "%d", &shift) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    fputs ("\ninput : ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (text, MAXC, stdin))
        return 0;
    
    text[strcspn(text, "\n")] = 0;      /* trim trailing \n */
    
    do  /* encode text */
        encode[n] = encipher(text[n], shift);
    while (text[n++]);
    
    n = 0;
    do  /* decode encoded text */
        decode[n] = decipher(encode[n], shift);
    while (encode[n++]);
    
    printf ("encode: %s\ndecode: %s\n", encode, decode);
}
```

(**note:** in practice with encryption the encoding is rarely represented as a nul-terminated string. Here since the result is limited to ASCII characters that is a convenience for output and fine for the exercise, but generally you will only store encoded values and a count of the number of characters)

**Example Use/Output**

Checking both uppercase and lowercase with the alphabet:

```
$ ./bin/ceasar_cipher
enter shift: 3

input : ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
encode: XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
decode: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Checking against the wikipedia example:

```
$./bin/ceasar_cipher
enter shift: 3

input : THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
encode: QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD
decode: THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.